# Convolutional Neural Networks for identification of specific objects instead of object categories?

Tags: references, conv-neural-network, identifiability, object-detection, named-entity-recognition

Is it for example feasible to hand a query image of my dog "Dave" to a CNN, and then use the CNN to find all images of "Dave" in a database of dog images?

If so, how would one do this?

If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. In this case *Dave* and *not Dave* would be the output categories. Though, you can't just give it one image and have it find all the others. If you turned the learning rate up high enough for it to learn what *Dave* is from one image, it would probably severely overfit; if not, it wouldn't learn enough. Also, with just one training example you can't use a validation set for meta-parameter tuning or test set for testing. It's like any other classifier network. Give the network as much training data as you can collect, and have at it!

If you do want a solution which let's you use a single image KNN would work, but it's effectively a severely overfit classifier in this case.

Comment: In this use case I have only a single image, thus overfitting would be a major problem indeed. But I was thinking that using a CNN to create something of a feature vector might be a solution. And then use a feature vector in combination with, perhaps, KNN? Or is that not something one can do with a CNN?

Comment: To my knowledge you end up in the same place. Learning features from a single example will pretty much be the same as just using KNN to begin with. I guess you could manually train it somehow (this is an eye, this is a nose, *Dave* is golden-brown, etc... I advise manually finding more pictures of *Dave* and using them to train the network.